# TensorFlow, Android Studio and Bazel: Setting up a New Project

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, tensorflow, bazel

I'm trying to use TensorFlow in an Android mobile app to infer on a model.  First, I have already built and tested a TensorFlow graph; it is saved as a protobuf file.  Next, I have the toolchain setup and I have built and run the [Inception Android demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android).  My next step is to create a fresh Android project in Android Studio (with C++ enabled) following the Android [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#create-sources).  I've created the JNI Hello World app, it compiles and runs on a Nexus.  But when I tried to import 'org.tensorflow', I can't get Android Studio (AS) to recognize it.  So, my primary question is: how to bring TensorFlow into my Demo app.
For example, I created a simple class to start with:

```
package com.foobar.tfdemo; 

import org.tensorflow.contrib.android.TensorFlowInferenceInterface;

public class TensorFlowClassifier implements Classifier {
// do something
}
```

But Android Studio cannot resolve `org.tensorflow`.
Possible options:
1) Modify `build.gradle` to compile TF into the project (using Bazel)
2) Externally compile a TF library (.so) and import it, or 
3) Use CMakeList.txt to import a TF library

In detail:

Option 1) Modify `build.gradle`.
   I used the Inception `build.gradle` as a model and copied over most of it.  The same `import org.tensorflow` still doesnt resolve, even though there are no other errors.  Here is the `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
def bazel_location = '/usr/local/bin/bazel'
def cpuType = 'armeabi-v7a'
def nativeDir = 'libs/' + cpuType

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.algoint.tfdemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

task buildNative(type:Exec) {
    workingDir '../../..'
    commandLine bazel_location, 'build', '-c', 'opt', \
      'tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_native_libs', \
       '--crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool', \
       '--cpu=' + cpuType, \
       '--host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain'
}

task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from('../../../bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/android') { include '**/*.so' }
    into nativeDir
    duplicatesStrategy = 'include'
}

copyNativeLibs.dependsOn buildNative
assemble.dependsOn copyNativeLibs
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleDebug') {
        task.dependsOn 'copyNativelibs'
    }
}
```

Option 2: Bring in a tensorflow library (.so) file.
I've spent a lot of time on this.  I've generated `libtensorflow_demo.so` using Bazel at the command line:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_native_libs --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --cpu=$CPU --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain
```

and placed it in both ~project/libs and ~project/src/app/src/main/jniLibs.  But nothing I do seems to help.

Option 3: Use CMakeList.txt to compile tensorflow.
I haven't spent much time on this.  I don't think `CMakeList.txt` will be able to invoke Bazel or import an .so file.  I think it needs a .a file instead.

So, how have others gone about incorporating Tensorflow into Android projects?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It recently became a lot easier to embed a pre-trained TensorFlow model in your Android app.  Check out my blog posts here:
https://medium.com/@daj/using-a-pre-trained-tensorflow-model-on-android-e747831a3d6 (part 1)
https://medium.com/@daj/using-a-pre-trained-tensorflow-model-on-android-part-2-153ebdd4c465 (part 2)

My blog post goes into more detail, but in summary, all you need to do is:

1. Include the compile `org.tensorflow:tensorflow-android:+` dependency in your build.gradle.
2. Use the Java `TensorFlowInferenceInterface` class to interface with your model (no need to modify any of the native code).

FYI, the TensorFlow Android demo app has been updated to use this new approach.  See [TensorFlowImageClassifier.recognizeImage](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/TensorFlowImageClassifier.java#L127) for where it uses the `TensorFlowInferenceInterface`.

You'll still need to specify some configuration, like the names of the input and output nodes in the graph, and the size of the input, but since you built your own TensorFlow graph, you probably know this information. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/android/cmake

And in `debugCompile` and `releaseCompile` instead of `tensorflow_inference` use `TensorFlow-Android-Inference`.

This worked for me.